# How does memory alloc work in C? // What's wrong w my code?

Tags: arrays, c, memory-management, printf, nested-loops

New to programming, I am solving a problem where I am supposed to print a square pattern of decreasing numbers such that `5` would give:

```
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 
5 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 2 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 2 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 
5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

I thought of using arrays and repeatedly subtracting from the array and printing it to solve this;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    // Complete the code to print the pattern.
    int *arr;
    int k = 1;
    arr = calloc(2 * n - 1, sizeof(char));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++) {
        *(arr + i) = n;
    }
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        for (int i = k; i < 2 * n - 1 - k; i++) {
            arr[i] = arr[i] - 1;
        }
        k++;
        
    } while (k <= n);
    
    k = n - 1;
    
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        
        for (int i = k; i < 2 * n - 1 - k; i++) {
            arr[i]++;
        }
        k--;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This works in Visual studio code, but not on the compiler on the site, and neither on another online compiler I tested it on. I'm assuming I messed up on the `calloc` part. What's the problem here?

Comment: What you're proposing could be made to work, but there really isn't a need for memory allocation.  You don't use any string or mathematical functions, so you don't need the `<string.h>` and `<math.h>` headers, either.

Comment: You removed this challenge from Hacker Rank

Comment: If you are gonna use scanf to read integers you have to use a width specifier, "%4d" for example and know that the width fits the type you use. Otherwise it will be undefiend behaviour if it overflows.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(int)`, not `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: Impressive there's no good dupe target. I only found one for `sizeof(int)` vs `sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: You should combine both answers into a single one with some explanations...

Comment: @chqrlie Looks like you have already taken my answers and expanded on them, so no need.

Comment: @MarkAdler: yep, couldn't resist, hot summer day...

Comment: I went for a long walk. Might be healthier.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach with a dynamically allocated array is 1) unsafe and 2) inefficient.

Firstly, you need to check whether the user entered a valid positive number in this call of scanf

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

Also you need to check whether a memory was allocated successfully. And you have correctly to specify the size of element of the allocated array. That is you need to use expression `sizeof( int )` instead of `sizeof( char )`

```
arr = calloc(2*n-1, sizeof(int));
```

Thirdly, you need to know the width of the maximum outputted value. Otherwise the table with the pattern will not be correctly aligned. For example try to run your program when `n` is equal to `10`.

Also your program has too many loops.

And at last you need to free the allocated memory.

To output the pattern there is no any need to allocate dynamically memory. It is enough to use only one pair of nested for loops and the function `printf`.

Here is a demonstration program. The trick of the program is using these two expressions

```
int value_for_row    = abs( n - i - 1 ) + 1;
int value_for_column = abs( n - j - 1 ) + 1;
```

Investigate them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    //  The value of the constant MAX_WIDTH of the pattern 
    //  may be any positive number not greater than INT_MAX / 2
    const int MAX_WIDTH = 100;

    while (1)
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number not greater than %d (0 - exit): ", MAX_WIDTH );

        int n;

        if ( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 || ( n <= 0 )) break;

        if ( MAX_WIDTH < n ) n = MAX_WIDTH;

        int item_width = 1;

        for (int tmp = n; tmp /= 10; ) ++item_width;

        putchar( '\n' );

        for ( int i = 0, m = 2 * n - 1; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                int value_for_row    = abs( n - i - 1 ) + 1;
                int value_for_column = abs( n - j - 1 ) + 1;

                int current_item = value_for_row < value_for_column 
                    ? value_for_column
                    : value_for_row;

                printf( "%*d ", item_width, current_item );
            }
            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number not greater than 100 (0 - exit): 1

1

Enter a non-negative number not greater than 100 (0 - exit): 2

2 2 2
2 1 2
2 2 2

Enter a non-negative number not greater than 100 (0 - exit): 3

3 3 3 3 3
3 2 2 2 3
3 2 1 2 3
3 2 2 2 3
3 3 3 3 3

Enter a non-negative number not greater than 100 (0 - exit): 4

4 4 4 4 4 4 4
4 3 3 3 3 3 4
4 3 2 2 2 3 4
4 3 2 1 2 3 4
4 3 2 2 2 3 4
4 3 3 3 3 3 4
4 4 4 4 4 4 4

Enter a non-negative number not greater than 100 (0 - exit): 5

5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5
5 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 2 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 2 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 5
5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5

Enter a non-negative number not greater than 100 (0 - exit): 10

10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
10  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 10
10  9  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  9 10
10  9  8  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  9 10
10  9  8  7  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  8  9 10
10  9  8  7  6  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  7  8  9 10
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  3  3  3  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  2  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  2  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  3  3  3  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
10  9  8  7  6  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  7  8  9 10
10  9  8  7  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  8  9 10
10  9  8  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  9 10
10  9  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  9 10
10  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 10
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

Enter a non-negative number not greater than 100 (0 - exit): 0
```

Answer (score 1):

> How does memory alloc work in C? // What's wrong w my code?

There is indeed a major problem with your allocation statement which is causing undefined behavior, consistent with your observations: the code may work as expected on some targets and not on others.

You allocate memory for `2 * n - 1` entries in `arr` with `arr = calloc(2 * n - 1, sizeof(char));`  The problem is `arr` is an array of `int` so the element size should be `sizeof(int)`. By allocating `2 * n - 1` bytes, you are causing undefined behavior when the code writes beyond the end of the allocated block.

Here is a safer approach: always use the size of target entry type:

```
int *arr = calloc(2 * n - 1, sizeof(*arr));
```

Also note that you should check for `scanf` and `calloc` failure and free the memory when it is no longer needed.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int width = 2 * n - 1;
    int *arr = calloc(width, sizeof(*arr));
    if (arr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        for (int i = k; i < width - k; i++) {
            arr[i] = n - k;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (int k = n - 2; k >= 0; k--) {
        for (int i = k; i < width - k; i++) {
            arr[i] = n - k;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that the code can be further simplified, without memory allocation, by computing the printed values on the fly from a simple mathematical formula:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int max(int a, int b) { return a > b ? a : b; }

int main(void) {
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int k = 1 - n; k <= n - 1; k++) {
        for (int j = 1 - n; j <= n - 1; j++) {
            printf("%d ", 1 + max(abs(k), abs(j)));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just:

```c
    for (int i = -n + 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = -n + 1; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d ", 1 + (abs(i) > abs(j) ? abs(i) : abs(j)));
        putchar('\n');
    }
```

?